# Many names of JavaScript / ECMA

Tags: javascript, e4x, ecma262

I was looking up newer functions of JavaScript and found ECMAScript/ECMA 5.

Because I had never heard of it I looked in to it more and found that it comes in the form of different names such as:

```
JavaScript, JScript (Microsofts Variation), ECMAScript, ECMA 5, E4X (JavaScript for Xml)and many others
```

From what I have read it seems that whilst a newer implementation of JavaScript is being drafted it is called ECMA-262 edition {edition_number} or {name}.

I know that each one is a dialect if an implementation of ECMAScript, so it would work in the same if not a slightly different way.

Are JavaScript and ECMAScript different in any way or is it just the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ECMAScript is a standard. Javascript, JScript are implementations of that standard.**

And yes they are [almost](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/named-function-expressions/) the same. Most of the differences in web programming come from the diversity of DOM implementations (Document Object Model).

Comment: Exactly what I thought it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's mostly just the name.

Javascript was first implemented, then the ECMAScript standard was drafted to describe it.

Comment: That's what I thought. So when say ActionScript was created it was based on the ECMAScript Standard?

Comment: Yes. ActionScript also implements ECMAScript.

Answer (score 0):

Same. ECMAScript is the language, Javascript is the name of the implementation in web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

HOWEVER if you stick to JavaScript when you code for browsers, you will be the most compatible.